# PHPExcel character errors

Tags: excel, encoding, export, character, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to write data from Sql database to Excel file.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A$sl", $contactname);
```

Right before the above line, I checked `$contactname` encoding, and result is `ASCII`, meaning `utf8`.

However, after the Excel file is generated, when I open it, I can see that `&eacute;` instead of é.

Could you please help? I have gone through similar questions, but nothing seems to solve it.

Comment: "result is ASCII, meaning utf8": No `ASCII` != `UTF8`. `ASCII` is part of `UTF8`. But "é" is not contained in `ASCII`. And: "i can see that é instead of é":??? Then everything is alright though.

Comment: Thank you for help Axel. It seems alright, but when i open my generated  excel file, it contains $eacute;. The point is when i echo $contactname, it prints with "é", and echo mb_detect_encoding($contactname) gives ASCII as result.